# Alerts on upgraded Sitecollection, 2013

Tags: 2013, email, administration

After successfully upgrading SharePoint 2010 to 2013, we noticed that you can set up Alerts on any lists or libraries and get an instant email notification that the Alert has been created, but no mails while a new item or an update has occurred.

The timer job is always successful ( every 5 minute ) and i tried several times to run it manually. The UPS is up and running and all the user properties are correct. The Alerts display the correct email.

Has anyone else had this problem after a farm migration?

**Update**

I did try to create a new list, set up alerts on it and received the subscription mail as expected but still no mail after creating a new list item. I did try to disable and re-enable the permissions "create alerts" and "manage alerts" for the web application and after that i get en email notification from the new list.

But still nothing from the migrated lists so i think the email URL for the old list need to be updated. Any suggestions?

**Update 2**

After about half an hour later all the email for the old lists started working, so i guess that there were something wrong with the alert permissions after migrating from 2010. Disabling and enabling the permissions on the web application level sorted it out.

Comment: does user have mroe than read access to the library/list?

Comment: All the lists inherits permissions where all the user for the current site collection have contribute permission, so yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After about half an hour later all the email for the old lists started working, so i guess that there were something wrong with the alert permissions after migrating from 2010. Disabling and enabling the permissions on the web application level sorted it out.

( Create Alerts  -  Create alerts *and* Manage Alerts  -  Manage alerts for all users of the Web site.  )